# Using C# 7.1 with MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.1

To use the new [C# 7.1 language features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1) with Visual Studio 2017, you add the setting `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your project file(s).

However, building such projects from MSBuild (version 15.3.409.57025, located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`) results in an error:

```
CSC : error CS1617: Invalid option 'latest' for /langversion;
must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.
```

Is this feature just not yet supported by MSBuild, or is it possible to get this working?

This covers 200+ projects that were originally created variously in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. They were all re-targeted to .NET 4.7 using the [Target Framework Migrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PavelSamokha.TargetFrameworkMigrator) tool (which saved *lots* of clicking and appears - based on inspecting .csproj file changes - to do the job correctly).

The projects all build successfully from Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: are you able to share your csproj file content?

Comment: Where does your MSBuild reside? Here it resides in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` and adding the language element does work. Does your project build from Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you show the except of your project file?

Comment: Do the project maybe reference the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package? if so, it needs to be updated to get a compiler version that supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that our MVC projects were triggering this issue.

To fix, we updated the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` NuGet package used by these projects from version **1.0.0** to **1.0.7**.

Comment: Besides this I also had to update `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`.

Answer (score 28):

#### Nuget packages

- `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package does not work and **needn't** to be installed.

#### Set the following `project/build settings`

- Set at least `C# 7.1` or higher in the `Debug` **and**  `Release` build properties. (via: Project menu > [ProjectName] Properties > Build tab > [Advanced] button > Language Version).
- Setting it to latest does **not** work.

[image: preview]

Also make sure that you are running the latest MSBuild version.

Comment: Bingo! This was the right answer for me to get it working with TFS & MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks!  Removing the Microsoft.Net.Compilers fixed this issue... and made it easier to upgrade some other items.

Comment: Language version drop down is disabled for my project. I'm using vs 2019 Enterprise. It is a console application project.

Answer (score 8):

Add a reference to the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) package (version 2.3.x, to get C# 7.1).

A short [description of the package](http://aka.ms/roslyn-packages):

> Microsoft.Net.Compilers
>
> This package not only includes the C# and
>   Visual Basic compilers, it also modifies MSBuild targets so that the
>   included compiler versions are used rather than any system-installed
>   versions. Once installed, this package requires Microsoft Build Tools
>   2015.

Comment: This did the trick for me.  I had the package in my main project, but today I updated a referenced project to C# 7.1 and forgot it didn't have this NuGet package.  I received this exact issue - builds in VS but fails on the build server.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Actually...  My problem was also caused by me changing the value in DEBUG project property settings.  Visiting the RELEASE settings found it was still C# (latest major version).  Changing that, checking in and doing another build.  Happy now :)

Comment: Thats what fixed it for me @Ian Yates. Thanks.

Comment: Only this solution helped me to fix it

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have changed for "All Configuration" and not just "Debug"

[image]

[image]

else you will be baffling why it is failing at production.

Answer (score 3):

In case you land here because you get the error as the OP mentioned, running **msbuild via command line** (e.g. from a build agent such as *jenkins*), the solution may be as easy as to **upgrade Microsoft Build Tools 2015**.

You can do that via [choco install microsoft-build-tools](https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools) or manually via the official [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) or by updating your Visual Studio 2017 installation.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution with a C# console app using C# 7.1 here.

Using the VS 2017 command line (and thus MSBuild 15.3.409.57025) it worked fine. (The `.csproj` does contain `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`.)

> Is this feature just not yet supported by MSBuild, or is it possible to get this working?

Yes it is.

Which instance of `csc.exe` is being run and what's its version? Because it looks like, despite quoting the version, you have the wrong version of `csc.exe` (the error message says `1-6` so not even C# 7 would work).

Comment: What exactly is the solution you propose? It all seems to be running fine out of the box as described in the procedures from OP.

Comment: @Richard - updated my question to address some of your queries

Comment: @PatrickHofman Updated to make it clear I'm addressing the existential part of the question.