# Invalid option '7.2' for /langversion For ASP.NET Application after Visual Studio 2017 Upgrade from Professional to Enterprise

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have just updated my `Visual Studio` from `Visual Studio Professional 2017` to `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`. Immediately I got these errors for compilation of my ASP.NET Web Application.

```
Invalid option '7.2' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6. For the file CSC
```

The solutions on the internet told me to change the Language version to C# 7.0 from default and to reinstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.
Changing to C# 7.0 did not work and I don't have this dll.

In fact I don't have a  section in my web.config file so I can not change the language here or the type or anything.

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Does anyone have any ideas? Why don't I have a  section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C# 7.1 with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419760/using-c-sharp-7-1-with-msbuild)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very silly!

After I downloaded the new `Enterprise Visual Studio 2017` I did not do any updates and so the default version (which selects the highest) was only c# 7.0. My project was for c# 7.2.
So I updated `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` and now I had up to version C# 7.3.
And my application compiles now.

Comment: Only required download .Net framework. It was enough for me.